# Помогите составить алгоритм парсинга короткой строки

Tags: javascript, алгоритм, регулярные-выражения

Написал алгоритм, который упаковывает объект в строку, которая вставляется в ссылку. Теперь на сайте, где используется эта ссылка, нужно эту строку распарсить обратно в объект. Примеры таких ссылок:

- `MOW2302SIP1` Москва - Питер, вылет 23.02, 1 взрослый пассажир
- `MOW2302SIP24021` Москва - Питер, вылет 23.02, обратно 24.02, 1 взрослый пассажир
- `MOW2303SIP240211` Москва - Питер, вылет 23.02, обратно 24.02, 1 взрослый, 1 подросток
- `MOW2303SIP2402111` Москва - Питер, вылет 23.02, обратно 24.02, 1 взрослый, 1 подросток, 1 младенец
- `MOW2303SIP240211b` Москва - Питер, вылет 23.02, обратно 24.02, 1 взрослый, 1 подросток, бизнес-класс
- `MOW1302LED1802TYO1` Москва - Питер 13.02, Питер - Токио 18.02, 1 взрослый
- `MOW1302KHV-VVO1802TYO1` Москва - Хабаровск, 13.02, Владивосток - Токио 18.02, 1 взрослый

Как видите, в алгоритме есть определённые закономерности. Например, чтобы обозначить два города и вылет из первого во второй, используется формат CODDATECOD, где COD - код города, а DATE - дата вылета из первого во второй.

Из этого приходит идея использовать регулярку `/([A-Z]{3}[0-9]{4}[A-Z]{3})/g`, которой выдёргивать нужные маршруты, а далее уже просто по остаточному принципу смотреть, что идёт после каждой из этих строк и делать выводы о том, есть ли обратная дата, сколько пассажиров и какой класс, но в таком случае весь алгоритм ломает предпоследняя строка `MOW1302LED1802TYO1`, где, если город прибытия в первом сегменте совпадает с городом отправки во втором, то он дублируется. А если города не совпадают, то создаётся новый сегмент, разделённый дефисом, как показано в последнем примере строки. И как распарсить это в таком случае я ума не приложу.

Comment: @Igor так того требует ТЗ ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: @Igor это легко решается административным  на количество пассажиров

Comment: А при помощи чего будет парситься на сайте? Если Node.js, то какой версии?

Comment: И ещё непонятно, ограничена ли длина цепочки только двумя рейсами или их может быыть любое количество (т.е. вомзожно ли Москва - Питер, Владивосток - Токио, Токио - Вашингтон, Нью-Йорк - Сидней).

Comment: @Igor одновременно может быть максимум 9 пассажиров любого типа.

Comment: @vsemozhetbyt javascript на клиенте.

Comment: @vsemozhetbyt максимум 6

Answer (score 4):

**Вариант для динамичных кодов**

```js
var tests = {"MOW2302SIP1": "Москва - Питер, вылет 23.02, 1 взрослый пассажир",
"MOW2302SIP24021": "Москва - Питер, вылет 23.02, обратно 24.02, 1 взрослый пассажир",
"MOW2303SIP240211": "Москва - Питер, вылет 23.02, обратно 24.02, 1 взрослый, 1 подросток",
"MOW2303SIP2402111": "Москва - Питер, вылет 23.02, обратно 24.02, 1 взрослый, 1 подросток, 1 младенец",
"MOW2303SIP240211b": "Москва - Питер, вылет 23.02, обратно 24.02, 1 взрослый, 1 подросток, бизнес-класс",
"MOW1302LED1802TYO1": "Москва - Питер 13.02, Питер - Токио 18.02, 1 взрослый",
"MOW1302KHV-VVO1802TYO1" : "Москва - Хабаровск, 13.02, Владивосток - Токио 18.02, 1 взрослый",
"MOW1302SEL2702TYO1903LAX-SFO2703NYC1": "Москва - Сеул 13.02, Сеул - Токио 27.02, Токио - Лос-Анджелес 19.03, Сан-Франциско - Нью-Йорк 23.03, 1 взрослый пассажир"
};

var rx_master = /^([A-Z]{3}(?:\d{4})?(?:-?[A-Z]{3}(?:\d{4})?)*)(\d?)(\d?)(\d?)([a-z]?)$/; // https://regex101.com/r/QHUYlr/1
var rx_flights = /(?:-([A-Z]{3})(\d{4})?(?=([A-Z]{3}))|([A-Z]{3})(\d{4})?(?=([A-Z]{3})))(?=(?:[A-Z]{3}(\d{4})(?=\d{0,3}[a-z]?$))?)/g;
for (var t in tests) {
  console.log(t);
  var m, res = [];
  if (m = rx_master.exec(t)) {
      res.push({ 
        'adult': (m[2] ? parseInt(m[2]) : 0),
        'child': (m[3] ? parseInt(m[3]) : 0),
        'baby': (m[4] ? parseInt(m[4]) : 0),
        'class': (m[5] ? "business" : "")});
      var n, prev_dest = "";
      while (n = rx_flights.exec(m[1])) {
          flight = {};
          if (prev_dest.length > 0 && n[4]) {
              flight.origin = prev_dest;
          } else {
              flight.origin = n[1] ? n[1] : n[4];
          }
          prev_origin = (n[4] ? n[6] : n[3]);
          flight.date = (n[4] ? (n[5] ? n[5] : "") : (n[2] ? n[2] : ""));
          flight.destination = (n[4] ? n[6] : n[3]);
          prev_dest = flight.destination;
          flight.returndate = (n[7] ? n[7] : "");
          res.push(flight);
      }
  }
  console.log("Результат:", res);
  console.log("Искомое:", tests[t]);
}
```

**Вариант ответа для фиксированных кодов**

Предлагаю использовать три регулярных выражения, каждое из которых будет возвращать совпадение только полной строки, для трёх типов кодов: 1) с 1 по 5, 2) для шестого, 3) для седьмого.

Для того, чтобы код работал как нужно, дополните города в `cities`. Лучше ещё добавить обработку ошибок (если можно ввести коды городов и другие неверно).

```js
var tests = {"MOW2302SIP1": "Москва - Питер, вылет 23.02, 1 взрослый пассажир",
"MOW2302SIP24021": "Москва - Питер, вылет 23.02, обратно 24.02, 1 взрослый пассажир",
"MOW2303SIP240211": "Москва - Питер, вылет 23.02, обратно 24.02, 1 взрослый, 1 подросток",
"MOW2303SIP2402111": "Москва - Питер, вылет 23.02, обратно 24.02, 1 взрослый, 1 подросток, 1 младенец",
"MOW2303SIP240211b": "Москва - Питер, вылет 23.02, обратно 24.02, 1 взрослый, 1 подросток, бизнес-класс",
"MOW1302LED1802TYO1": "Москва - Питер 13.02, Питер - Токио 18.02, 1 взрослый",
"MOW1302KHV-VVO1802TYO1" : "Москва - Хабаровск, 13.02, Владивосток - Токио 18.02, 1 взрослый" };
var cities = { "MOW": "Москва", "LED": "Питер", "SIP": "Питер", "KHV": "Хабаровск", "VVO": "Владивосток", "TYO": "Токио"};
var rx1 = /^([A-Z]{3})(\d{2})(\d{2})([A-Z]{3})(?:(\d{2})(\d{2}))?(\d?)(\d?)(\d?)([a-z]?)$/; // https://regex101.com/r/p7dXN3/1
var rx2 = /^([A-Z]{3})(\d{2})(\d{2})([A-Z]{3})(\d{2})(\d{2})([A-Z]{3})(\d?)(\d?)(\d?)([a-z]?)$/; // https://regex101.com/r/p7dXN3/4
var rx3 = /^([A-Z]{3})(\d{2})(\d{2})([A-Z]{3})-([A-Z]{3})(\d{2})(\d{2})([A-Z]{3})(\d?)(\d?)(\d?)([a-z]?)$/; // https://regex101.com/r/p7dXN3/5

for (var t in tests) {
  console.log(t);
  var m, res;
  if (m = rx1.exec(t)) {
      res = cities[m[1]] + " - " + cities[m[4]] + 
          ", вылет " + m[2] + "." + m[3] +  // Вылет
          (m[5] ? ", обратно "+m[5]+"."+m[6] : "") + // Обратно (необязательно)
          ", " + m[7] + " взрослый пассажир" + // Взрослый (обязателен)
          (m[8] ? ", " + m[8] + " подросток" : "") + // Подросток (необязателен)
          (m[9] ? ", " + m[9] + " младенец" : "") + // Младенец (необязателен)
          (m[10] ? ", бизнес-класс" : "");         // Бизнес-класс (необязателен)
  } else if (m = rx2.exec(t)) { // $1 - $4, вылет $2.$3, $4 - $7, вылет $5.$6, $8 взрослый пассажир, $9 подросток, $10 младенец, $11
      res = cities[m[1]] + " - " + cities[m[4]] + 
          ", вылет " + m[2] + "." + m[3] +  // Вылет
          ", " + cities[m[4]] + " - " + cities[m[7]] +
          ", вылет " + m[5] + "." + m[6] +  // Вылет
          ", " + m[8] + " взрослый пассажир" + // Взрослый (обязателен)
          (m[9] ? ", " + m[9] + " подросток" : "") + // Подросток (необязателен)
          (m[10] ? ", " + m[10] + " младенец" : "") + // Младенец (необязателен)
          (m[11] ? ", бизнес-класс" : "");         // Бизнес-класс (необязателен)
  } else if (m = rx3.exec(t)) {
  //$1 - $4, вылет $2.$3, $5 - $8, вылет $6.$7, $9 взрослый пассажир, $10 подросток, $11 младенец, $12
      res = cities[m[1]] + " - " + cities[m[4]] + 
          ", вылет " + m[2] + "." + m[3] +  // Вылет
          ", " + cities[m[5]] + " - " + cities[m[8]] +
          ", вылет " + m[6] + "." + m[7] +  // Вылет
          ", " + m[9] + " взрослый пассажир" + // Взрослый (обязателен)
          (m[10] ? ", " + m[10] + " подросток" : "") + // Подросток (необязателен)
          (m[11] ? ", " + m[11] + " младенец" : "") + // Младенец (необязателен)
          (m[12] ? ", бизнес-класс" : "");         // Бизнес-класс (необязателен)
  }
  console.log("Результат:", res);
  console.log("Искомое:", tests[t]);
}
```

**Подробности регулярки №1**

- `^` - начало строки
- `([A-Z]{3})` - Группа №1: три заглавных буквы
- `(\d{2})(\d{2})` - Группа №2 и №3: по две цифры
- `([A-Z]{3})` - Группа №4: три заглавных буквы
- `(?:(\d{2})(\d{2}))?` - необязательная группа, находит и захватывает в группу №5 и №6 по две цифры
- `(\d?)` - Группа №7: 1 или 0 цифр
- `(\d?)` - Группа №8: 1 или 0 цифр
- `(\d?)` - Группа №9: 1 или 0 цифр
- `([a-z]?)` - Группа №10: 1 или 0 прописных букв
- `$` - конец строки.

Остальные две регулярки похожи на эту.

Comment: Огромное спасибо. Одни только регулярки достойны тысяч благодарностей.

Comment: @JamesJGoodwin Да, грамматику уж как-нибудь сами поправьте. `1 взрослый пассажир`, `2 взрослый пассажир`, `5 взрослый пассажир` как-то не очень. Может, `1 взрослый(ых) пассажир(а/ов)`. Обычно делают так: `Кол-во взрослых: 1`. На ваше усмотрение.

Comment: Хм, а на чём-то более сложном не работает. Например, `MOW1302SEL2702TYO1903LAX-SFO2703NYC1`

Comment: @JamesJGoodwin Нет, вы же не приводили таких примеров. Даже неясно, что тут к чему.

Comment: Москва - Сеул 13.02, Сеул - Токио 27.02, Токио - Лос-Анджелес 19.03, Сан-Франциско - Нью-Йорк 23.03, 1 взрослый пассажир. По сути, мне это всё нужно в виде объекта `[{origin: 'MOW', date: '1302', destination: 'SEL'}, {...}, ...]`.

Comment: На самом деле, ваша регулярка натолкнула меня на мысль. А зачем это всё парсить так сложно? Можно же просто сделать поиск по регулярке, которую я указал в самом вопросе. Если матч по такой регулярке всего один - маршрут простой, если таких 2 и более - маршрут сложный. И по сути, пассажиры и класс указываются всего 1 раз в самом конце. Поэтому алгоритм таков - если маршрут простой, то спарсить `MOW2301LED`. Затем проверить, есть ли после LED ещё какая-то дата (обратная). Вопрос только в том, как лучше спарсить в конце пассажиров, ведь в простом маршруте может сливаться с датами (напр. 2303111)

Comment: @JamesJGoodwin Даты всегда идут после городов и кол-во цифр постоянно. Поэтому пассажиров в конце легко определить с помощью необязательных `(\d?)`.

Comment: @JamesJGoodwin Я тут ночью обновил ответ, посмотрите, пожалуйста. По-моему, двигаемся в верном направлении. Если что  непонятно, скажите — объясню.

Answer (score 0):

У меня получилось попроще и элегантнее. Достаточно просто найти все совпадения по регулярному выражению `/([A-Z]{3}[0-9]{4}[A-Z]{3})/g`. Осталось только распарсить пассажиров и обратную дату. Обратная дата может быть указана только в простом маршруте (когда `matches.length === 1`), поэтому после прохода регуляркой нужно проверить это условие и если оно `true`, то попытаться пройтись по нему либо каким-то регулярным выражением, которое проверит, идёт ли какая-либо дата после города назначения, или же после неё идут сразу пассажиры. Ну или просто сделать `switch(passengersStr.length) {}`

```js
var s = 'MOW1302KHV-VVO1802TYO1'
var r = /([A-Z]{3}[0-9]{4}[A-Z]{3})/g;
var m;
var lastIndex = 0
var matches = []

while (m = r.exec(s)) {
  r.lastIndex = m.index+1
  
  matches.push({
    origin: m[0].substring(0, 3),
    date: m[0].substring(3, 7),
    destination: m[0].substring(7, 10)
  })

  lastIndex = r.lastIndex
}

var passengersStr = s.substring(lastIndex + 9)

console.log(matches)
console.log('passengers: ' + passengersStr)
```